# How can I load the sectors of a usb drive into memory using assembly(8086)?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, kernel, x86-16, bootloader

I was studying about the multi-stage bootloaders where sectors are loaded from floppy using INT 13h. Now I am trying to load sectors of a usb into memory using the same INT 13h.

I assume my code as follows....

```
mov ah,02h ;sub function 2 to read sectors to memory
mov al,2 ;to read two sectors
mov cl,01h
mov dl,81h ;the second fixed disk
int 13h
```

I guess the above code is not exactly correct, but still, is this the way to load the sectors of a usb? I mean can I use the same 13h interrupt?
a
Any source code can be appreciated..

Comment: This was asked yesterday too. [How to load the sectors of a USB drive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311816/how-to-load-the-sectors-of-a-usb-drive?rq=1)

Comment: But it has no info described....

Comment: The info is that it *might* work on some systems, but not on others. The original 8086 hardware didn't *have* USB drives, so any BIOS support is an extension.

Comment: So, how can I achieve it? I dont find any souce on the net too.... please help..

Comment: I hope reading parameters via `int 13h` with `ah = 0x08` and accessing using the parameters just like HDD work.

Comment: But 8h is for drive parameters. What am I supposed to do with it? Thanks fr ur reply sir

Comment: Can you give me some code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access the USB port through the BIOS in 16-bit x86 real mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374185/how-do-i-access-the-usb-port-through-the-bios-in-16-bit-x86-real-mode), which I found with google in a few seconds.  Has 3 answers, all of which look useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to figure out what you want to do:

- Learning a multi-stage bootloader
- Programming a MBR code and loading it into the first sector of an USB
- Being able to boot-up a PC with such a program (enabling legacy option in the BIOS)
- Programming a second stage code to be stored in the following disk    sectors, which you want to be read from USB and placed in memory, in order to run it by jumping to the first instruction

¿right?
If your PC can boot from USB, then the following MBR code should read some sectors from the same device, store them in memory and jump to the first memory location in which it is supposed to be the first instruction of the second stage code. This code is to be assembled with nasm

> nasm -f bin filename

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]    ; this MBR code resides here (512 bytes)

boot:
mov ax,0x0100   ; stack lower bound
mov ss,ax       ; set stack at address 0x1000
mov sp,0x2000   ; 8KB stack

;load second stage code from disk to address 0x07e00 (just above)
read:
xor ax,ax       ; Floppy Reset BIOS Function
                ; DL -> device (BIOS left 0x0:floppy or 0x80:HDD)
int 0x13        ; unnecesary to set DL because BIOS did the work
jc read

mov ax,0x07e0
mov es,ax   ; SEGMENT
xor bx,bx   ; OFFSET
xor dh,dh   ; dh=0 (head); dl = device
mov cx,2    ; ch=0 (cilinder) ; cl = 2 (1st sector, number 2)
mov ax,2*256+17 ; ah=2 (read); al=17 (sectors)
int 0x13
jc read     ;retry jump in case of read error

stop:
mov dx,0x3F2 ; stop the motor from spinning
mov al,0x0C  ; unnecesary in case of USB, only for floppy
out dx,al 

;jump to second stage code (first intruction at very beggining)
mov ax,0x07e0
mov ds,ax
jmp 0x07e0:0x0


TIMES 510-($-$$) DB 0

SIGNATURE DW 0xAA55
```

Hope this help!

Comment: One more doubt...With the code you provided(Thanks again)..can I place my stage 2 file anywhere on my USB or on a specific sector....

Comment: Please answer my ques Sergio.Uma  also why dl register is not given any value?

Comment: Stage 2 can be placed on any other sector, but modify accordingly head, cilinder and sector (dh, ch and cl registers). If USB is formated for a file system, usually first track (track0) is unused, so you have 63 sectors available.

Comment: BIOS search for a MBR signature in different disks, when it is found BIOS copies such 512 bytes to memory and jump to it. I guess that such copying is done via INT 13h, so BIOS set dl register to point at the currently used disk, so you dont need to set or modify if second stage is on the same device where the MBR is